# How copy main files from bower componentns?

Tags: javascript, build, webpack

Bower have such structure

```
-bower_components
--lib
---dist
----lib.js
```

I need copy file from main in bower.json to libs

```
-libs
--lib.js
```

How can i make this with webpack?

P.s I don't need use require, need only copy files.